# Does my PWM led circuit controlled with NodeMCU and Mosfet work properly. What should I do to improve it? How to calculate for each components?

Tags: led, mosfet, pwm

If I understand it right, when there's is signal from ESP, the PNP and NPN be ON, and Vgs=0. If they're OFF Vgs=+12V and the LED will shine. R=1K is to limit the Ib of NPN, and R=10K is the resistor pull up for the Gate. for the 2 Resistors=4.7K is to limit the Ic,right? 
[image]

Comment: IRF540N is a N type FET. Think about what Vgs is needed to drive it on and off, and where you measure Vgs.

Comment: i just use a single nchan, the led, and the mcu; why is this circuit so complex?

Comment: I want to make increase Vgs so I add transistor to control the Mosfet through Ib. But I don't exactly know how to calculate to choose approriate Resistor and transistor. I just randomly add number in this